# Two different Bootstrap modal windows...both opening at once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've found several similar questions, but none seem to quite give the answer I need. I have a page that required two different modal windows. One opens by clicking any one of 8 buttons (the modal content is the samen no matter which you click), while the other is a simple "contact info" modal that opens when clicking a standard text link. The problem is that with this code, both modal windows open at the same time, one on top of the other, no matter which button/link you click. I need them to open separately, independent of each other.

Here's the scripts:

```
      <!--***********
MODAL WINDOW - SELECT TEMPLATE POPUP
 ***********-->
  <script>$('.selectLink').click(function() {
    $('.modal')
        .prop('class', 'modal fade') // revert to default
        .addClass( $(this).data('direction') );
    $('.modal').modal('show');
});</script>
<!--***********
MODAL WINDOW - SELECT TEMPLATE POPUP
 ***********-->

  <!--***********
MODAL WINDOW - HELP POPUP
 ***********-->
  <script>$('#helpLink').click(function() {
    $('.modal')
        .prop('class', 'modal fade') // revert to default
        .addClass( $(this).data('direction') );
    $('.modal').modal('show');
});</script>
<!--***********
MODAL WINDOW - HELP POPUP
 ***********-->
```

and the HTML:

```
<!-- MODAL WINDOW - SELECT TEMPLATE POPUP -->                  
    <div class="modal fade" class="selectLink" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h2 class="modal-title">Customize Your Email!</h4>
          </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
        ...
 </div>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->       
<!-- MODAL WINDOW - SELECT TEMPLATE POPUP --> 


        <!-- MODAL WINDOW - HELP POPUP   -->                
    <div id="helpLink" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h2 class="modal-title">Contact Us for Assistance</h4>
          </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
        ...          
 </div>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->       
<!-- MODAL WINDOW - HELP POPUP -->
```

I thought the issue might be that I'm using a class instead of an id for the "selectLink" modal, but before I added the second modal (with the id), that worked fine. I don't know a lot about jquery, so maybe I'm missing something in that section.

I've looked at several questions on SO, but none have quite given the necessary answer.

Comment: I uploaded jsFiddle example for you https://jsfiddle.net/zajzo8p7/, I open the modals clicking the spans,

Comment: Thanks @FranciscoFernandez! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line of JS:

```
$('.modal').modal('show');
```

It is saying "call the `modal('show')` function on all elements with class `modal`" It should refer to the specific modal by id, like this:

```
$('#helpLink').modal('show');
```

Or

```
$('#selectLink').modal('show');
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was something with the JS, thanks @DavidG! 
However, I edited the code as you described... now when I click the <a> link, the screen grays out, but no modal shows up... and when I click the button(s), the browser window goes completely black, everything disappears... I'm sure it's user error, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I see that you say "OR" between the two lines of JS. Should I only have one of those sections of JS? Or one should be specific, while the other is ".modal"?

Comment: I mean "or" as you haev 2 blocks of JS code. Put one of them in the first block and the other one in the other block.

Comment: That's how I read it... so I edited my question above, to reflect those changes. Is that right?

Comment: Unfortunately you have now completely changed your question which is really bad form as it makes the answer not valid any more.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know how else to easily show what I'm trying. I'll change it back to the original question.